java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonAutoConfiguration.loadBalancerClient
I am migrating the Springboot from 2.2.6.RELEASE to the 2.7.18 version with Spring cloud version 2021.0.3
Post that I am getting the below Exception:-
Can anyone please suggest which dependency/configuration changes I need to make to avoid this error?
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonAutoConfiguration.loadBalancerClient
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:756)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:572)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:409)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1289)
    at com.unilog.prime.tmb.TMBApplication.main(TMBApplication.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@76ed5528]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1684)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:239)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:229)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:182)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cloud/client/loadbalancer/LoadBalancedRetryPolicyFactory
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3578)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2676)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancedRetryPolicyFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 37 common frames omitted

Below things I tried but could not help.
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.netflix.ribbon</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ribbon-eureka</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
    </dependency>


Ribbon was removed

yes @spencergibb, I am using spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client and tried to exclude the ribbon as well but I am not sure from where it is getting that dependency and trying to access it.

Please check your dependencies, nothing in the new version of spring cloud includes ribbon. Something else is bringing it in.
